# Elif, if conditionals in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have trouble understanding this program.
As I understand, it should print `8` But it prints `33`. 
Please explain this to me. Thank you

```
x = "c"
y = 3
if "x" in "computer science":
    y = y + 5
else:
    y = y + 10
if x in "computer science":
    y = y + 20
else:
    y = y + 40
print (y)
```

Comment: `x` and `"x"` are not the same thing... namely in your case `x` is `"c"` but `"x"` is just...`"x"`

Comment: You need to look up a tutorial before posting a new question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The character (string, in python technically) `x` is not in the string `computer science` so the first if-else goes to the `else` statement and y is now 13.

However the character "c", which is the value of `x`, goes to the first block of the second if-else, and y is now 33.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood now. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is EXACTLY what's happening.

Comment: I absolutely didn't do it! Why would I. I am grateful. 
People are mean for beginners, whatever I ask, I get downvotes

Comment: @KyleKim I should have clarified (sorry), that comment wasn't aimed at you. Was aimed at whoever else downvoted. Thanks for the upvote, and happy coding!